# stroke-width of undefined, highcharts

Tags: angularjs, charts, highcharts, boxplot, highcharts-ng

I have implemented box plot in highcharts using highcharts-ng. The chart object has zoomType set to 'x', when i zoom in, it throws following error

**highcharts-more.js:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stroke-width' of undefined**.

This error also appears when series legend is clicked.
I have included highcharts-more.js in the bundle.config and it also shows up on the DOM.

Has someone encountered this issue before? and can someone please guide me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Share your code for configuring & showing highchart

Comment: Provide us with a working JSFiddle demo where this problem occurs. Thanks.